# SQL Group by Having > 1

Tags: sql, sybase, having

Maybe the title was not the best I could use to discribe the issue
an example of the table structure I am dealing with is in the image below. I need to write a query to pull all records for "Manufactures" that have more than one record. So the end result I would have LINUX UBUNTU 5.6  and LINUX REDHAT 7.8

Just returning the duplicated MANUFACTURE is easy and I can do that with using grouping having count(*) > 1 but when it comes to returning the duplicated manufacture and the corresponding columns with it is the issue I am coming up with.

[image: Table Example]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> returning the duplicated MANUFACTURE is easy and I can do that with using grouping `having count(*) > 1`

That's a good start. Now use that list of `manufacture`s to select the rest of the data:

```
SELECT *
FROM software
WHERE manufacture IN (
    -- This is your "HAVING COUNT(*) > 1" query inside.
    -- It drives the selection of rows in the outer query.
    SELECT manufacture
    FROM software
    GROUP BY manufacture
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

Comment: Although someone else gave the same answer this one was submitted first it looks like. because the actual query is not as clean as the example given it took a bit to get this answer to incorporate especially since the original query I wrote is already quite long and I am using linked server which limits the length of the query.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
  Select * from myTable
  Where Manufacture In
      (Select Manufacture
       from myTable
       Group By Manufacture
       Having count(*) > 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like:

```
select p.manufacture, p.product, p.version
from (select manufacture, count(*)
    from products
    group by manufacture) as my_count
inner join products as p on p.manufacture = my_count.manufacture
where my_count > 1
```

Comment: although this appears like it would work, an answer that is quite clean has already been given

Comment: Agreed, three almost identical answers posted at the same time.